# Teams Outgoing WebHook HMAC problem not matching

Tags: c#, api, blazor-server-side

I created an outgoing Teams webhook.
The callback URL points to a controller on my API, and I would like to use the HMAC provided by the webhook in the request header.

However, when I compute the HMAC with the secret key, I don't obtain the same key as the one in the header.

I tried this code :

```
protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                if (!this.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out var headerValue))
                {
                    return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Authorization header not found.");
                }

                var sentKey = headerValue.ToString().Replace("HMAC ", null);

                string requestBody = null;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(this.Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    requestBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(requestBody))
                {
                    return AuthenticateResult.Fail("No content to authenticate.");
                }

                var secretKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.Options.SecretKey);
                using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(secretKeyBytes))
                {
                    var hash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody));
                    var expectedSignature = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(hash);

                    if (!string.Equals(sentKey, expectedSignature, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    {
                        return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid HMAC signature.");
                    }
                }

                var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity();
                var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), this.Scheme.Name);

                return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail($"{ex.HResult}, {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer of my problem:

When I received the request I need to take the Body of the request  ((The model send by Teams in my case)(message)).

Read the Request. Body like this:

```
 private async Task<string?> ReadRequestBodyAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            this.Request.EnableBuffering();
            var encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(this.Request.Body, encoding, detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: false, bufferSize: 1024, leaveOpen: true))
            {
                var requestBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                this.Request.Body.Position = 0;
                return requestBody;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

After reading the body, transform it to BytesArrayUTF8 like this for creating a Hmac whit the secret key and compare it with the key sent in the request header:

```
 private bool IsValidSignature(string secretKey, string messageContent, string signature)
    {
        try
        {
            var keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(secretKey);

            using (var algorithm = new HMACSHA256(keyBytes))
            {
                var hash = algorithm.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageContent));

                var expectedHash = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);

                return expectedHash.Equals(signature);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```